# Is this a BUG of VC++ 2010? About declaring a constant object in a header

Tags: visual-c++, compile-time-constant

Several lines of code are worth a thousand words:

I have three simple files: header.h, main.cpp, other.cpp

```
==== CODE BEGIN ====

// header.h  
  #pragma once  

const void* p = 0;

// main.cpp

  #include "header.h"

int main()
{
    return 0;
}

// other.cpp

  #include "header.h"
==== CODE END ====
```

When compiling the simplest project, the VC++ 2010 complains as follows:

```
ClCompile:
  other.cpp
  main.cpp
  Generating Code...
other.obj : error LNK2005: "void const * const p" (?p@@3PBXB) already defined in main.obj
D:\Test\Debug\bug.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

Build FAILED.

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.29
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I am sure this is a bug of VC++ 2010, because of the following two references:

1. The C++ standard says: (at page 140 of n3126)

   > "Objects declared const and not
   >   explicitly declared extern have
   >   internal linkage."
2. The MSDN [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/357syhfh%28VS.80%29.aspx):

   > "In C, constant values default to
   >   external linkage, so they can appear
   >   only in source files. In C++, constant
   >   values default to internal linkage,
   >   which allows them to appear in header
   >   files.
   >
   > The const keyword can also be used
   >   in pointer declarations."

Comment: Did some formatting. Use the buttons above the edit field to format code and quotes correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const void *p = 0;` defines `p` as a pointer *to* `const void`, but does **not** define `p` itself to be `const` at all. Since your `p` is not a `const` object, the rule giving it internal linkage does not apply, so it has external linkage.

`void *const p = 0;` would define `p` as a const pointer. `void const * const p` would define `p` as a const pointer to const void.

Answer (score 2):

If you define the variable in a header file that is included more than once, the linker finds a definition for each inclusion.  You should *declare* the variable in the header file and *define* it once and only once, in a single .cpp file.

Header file:

```
extern const void* p;
```

cpp file:

```
const void* p = 0;
```

Comment: #pragma once

inline const int& GetConst()
{
 return 8;
}

const int& r = GetConst();

Comment: If I rewrite header.h as follows, then the compiler error will reoccur:#pragma once

inline const int& GetConst()
{
 return 8;
}

const int& r = GetConst();

Comment: However, a variable that has namespace scope and that is declared `const` has internal linkage.

Comment: @James - it would be good if OP could stop defining the variables in his header file.  That's a build blocker for him/her regardless of the nuances of the variable type.  Sorry for muddying the water.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it should be void* const p?