# Another BUG of VC++ 2010? About declaring a constant REFERENCE in a header

Tags: c++, visual-c++, reference, constants, linkage

Several lines of code are worth a thousand words:

I have three simple files: header.h, main.cpp, other.cpp

```
// header.h

  #pragma once

inline const int& GetConst()
{
    static int n = 0;
    return n;
}

const int& r = GetConst();

// main.cpp

  #include "header.h"

int main()
{
    return 0;
}

// other.cpp

  #include "header.h"
```

When compiling the simplest project, the VC++ 2010 complains as follows:

```
ClCompile:
  other.cpp
  main.cpp
  Generating Code...
  other.obj : error LNK2005: "int const & const r" (?r@@3ABHB) already defined in main.obj
D:\Test\Debug\bug.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

Build FAILED.

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.29
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I am sure this is a bug of VC++ 2010, because of the following two references:

1, The C++ standard says: (at page 140 of n3126)

"Objects declared const and not explicitly declared extern have internal linkage."

2, The MSDN says: (at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/357syhfh(VS.80).aspx)

"In C, constant values default to external linkage, so they can appear only in source files. In C++, constant values default to internal linkage, which allows them to appear in header files.

The const keyword can also be used in pointer declarations."

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is this a BUG of VC++ 2010? About declaring a constant object in a header.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185275/is-this-a-bug-of-vc-2010-about-declaring-a-constant-object-in-a-header)

Comment: Don't define variables in your header file (`r` in this case).  This is nothing to do with constness.  See dup question for fix.

Comment: I love how you assume this is a bug in a compiler used by millions, and couldn't be bothered to think it's a bug in your understanding of C++.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The paragraph you cite from the C++ Standard reads (C++03 7.1.1/6):

> Objects declared `const` and not explicitly declared `extern` have internal linkage.

You have not declared an object.  You have declared a reference.  A reference is not an object.  That said, 3.5/3 says:

> A name having namespace scope has internal linkage if it is the name of an object or reference that is explicitly declared const and neither explicitly declared `extern` nor previously declared to have external linkage

However, 8.3.2/1 says:

> Cv-qualified references are ill-formed

So, while a const-qualified reference would have internal linkage, it's not possible to const-qualify a reference.

The reference in your sample program is not const-qualified, it's a reference to a const-qualified `int`.

Comment: Thank you, James. Your explanation is concise and convincing!